# Strange HTTP GET Requests

Tags: http

My server has a static IP and listens to a port (8000) when it get's a file it automatically saves it with predefined extension. It's an internal project and no one knows about this server. I see few HTTP1.0/1.1 requests a day. should I be worried? They're origin is in Russia, Viet Nam and may be more.

Comment: these are "drive bys"; there's people who ping every IP address looking for open hosts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's an internal project and no one knows about this server.

Just because you did not tell anybody does not mean that nobody knows about it. Any host exposed to the internet is usually often checked for the kind of services if provides. Also the usual exploits are tried in the hope to find an easy target to take over and misuse, i.e. sending spam, delivering malware, attacking other systems within a DDoS attack, cryptomining, etc.

> ... should I be worried?

If your server is not secure you should be worried. It is better to keep the attack surface small, for example by requiring authentication, limiting access to specific IP addresses or whatever is possible in your specific use case.

Comment: it's not secure but then again all it does is save files. the only potential problem would be for them filling up my memory. the files aren't being opened by the system they are saved on

Comment: @DanielMeltzer: if you are sure that this is all what it does and has no functionality/bugs which you are not aware of then it might be sufficiently secure for your purpose.  But beware that their might also public accessible services outside this server you consider secure enough - for example it is also common to have brute force attacks against SSH (i.e. weak passwords).

Comment: I don't have password just a private key . it's 1024 bits. is it enough?

Comment: @DanielMeltzer: Key based authentication (also with RSA 1024 bit)  is fine as long as no password based authentication is possible too.